# how to clean flutter outdated pubs

Tags: flutter, dart-pub

As the image show, there are several versions of same pubs in my local:

- `.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/some-version1`.
- `.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/some-version2`.
- `.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/some-version3`.
- `.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/some-version4`.

Is there a way to clean them ?
Or clean them by provide a `minimal dart version`. (like `mini dart > 2.6.0`) ?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is a command for that. Because pub cannot know whether you have an old project lying around that depends on one of these older package versions or not.

The easiest way to clean away old packages is to just delete `.pub-cache` altogether. When you first run `flutter pub get` the ones that you actually use will be re-downloaded. This would get rid of the unused ones.

Comment: Not ideal, but is one of the correct way. I don’t like this way because it’s big folder (2.71G) for me, and my network isn’t very quickly. I can leave it alone for now.

Answer (score 0):

`flutter 1.17` provided a new commend: `flutter pub outdated`. which have good progress on this.

Answer (score 0):

Since Dart 2.14 there is:

```bash
flutter pub cache clean
```

Which will give you a prompt to chicken out:

> This will remove everything inside /Users/jannie/.pub-cache.
> You will have to run `flutter pub get` again in each project.
> Are you sure? (y/N)?

For more info, see [the docs](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/cmd/pub-cache#clearing-the-global-system-cache).